# Getting missing dependency error for 'Oracle.DataAccess' when deploying on IIS 64 Bit Server

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, odp.net, data-access

I am new to .Net. I created a code which connects to database and performs some transaction. For Data Access Manager, I added reference Oracle.DataAccess.86 (Oracle.DataAccess.dll) and Run with "Any CPU" in local. It works fine. But when I deploy it on server which has 64 Bit IIS running, then it's giving me below error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.    Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
>
> [BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
>       System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
>          System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +225
>          System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +110
>          System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +22
>          System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +34
>          System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +48

How can I find a solution for this error?

Comment: Check this question.  It sounds like a likely solution... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707101/how-to-compile-a-website-to-use-32-bit-oracle-client-on-64-bit-windows

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit All they have to do is set the AppPool to run as a 32 Bit app and it will rule that answer out, but they won't.  They don't need ODP.Net _**installed**_ if they have the prerequisite assemblies included in the project, but that's another question entirely.  Until OP answers the questions posed and responds accordingly to suggestions made then *everything* is pure guesswork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that wrong Oracle DLL being loaded into memory

If you build your assembly to AnyCPU...

**Requirement to run as x64** - Oracle Client x64 installed, Oracle.DataAccess.dll x64 deployed, AppPool set `"run 32 bit" = false`.

**Requirement to run as x86** - Oracle Client x86 installed, Oracle.DataAccess.dll x86 deployed, AppPool set `"run 32 bit" = true`.

**BUT** why would you use `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` in 2019? Use `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll`. Install small set of connectivity components (ODAC) and no need for Oracle client, x64/x86 - all will be done as AnyCPU. Better yet, install Oracle Development tools for Visual Studio, which will include ODAC

Answer (score 0):

If the IIS is 64 bit, then you also need the 64-bit version of `Oracle.DataAccess.dll`. I assume the Oracle.DataAccess is not installed at all on your server, please verify correct installation. Note, `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` requires an Oracle Client (typically the Oracle Instance Client), this must also be the same architecture as the `Oracle.DataAccess.dll`.

The reference to Oracle.DataAccess.dll is the same. The application (IIS in your case) will load the correct assembly automatically - provided it is installed and available on the machine. You may remove the `processorArchitecture=x86` attribute in your project file, you can edit the `*.csproj`, resp. `*.vbproj` file manually with a text editor.

Comment: Do you know this for sure?  The Application Pool can be run as a 32 Bit process, therefore not requiring (or working with) 64 Bit assemblies.  Have a look at the link I posted under the question for an example of this.

Comment: Please can you tell the reference i need to add for 64 bit version of Oracle.DataAccess.dll. Someone told me that there is no 64 bit Oracle.DataAccess.dll. I will confirm the correct installation.

Comment: Hi @Archer, checked that link. But i need to run it as 64 bit Process. That is part of requirement.

Comment: @Ashutosh Why is it part of the requirement?  If it's not possible then the requirements are invalid.

Comment: Of course there is a 64-bit version: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html